# Hibernate :QuerySyntaxException: AlertToEmployee.alert is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to create a join query with two classes Alert and AlertToEmployee ,

Class Alert :

```
public class Alert  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String object;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```

Class AlertToEmployee

```
public class AlertToEmployee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypeAffectation typeAffectation;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    @ManyToOne
    private Alert alert;
}
```

I create a  inner join query to have alerts with specific conditions, but I don't what matters with the mapping , I've got this error : `QuerySyntaxException: AlertToEmployee.alert is not mapped`

The query :

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.demo.shared.vo.AlertsVO(a.id,a.object  )" +
        "FROM  AlertToEmployee.alert a INNER JOIN  AlertToEmployee ate   ON a.id = ate.id WHERE a.isDeleted = false" +
        "  AND ate.registrationNumber = ?1 AND ate.isDeleted = false ")
```

I tried also this but it doesn't work too :

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.demo.shared.vo.AlertsVO(a.id,a.object  )" +
        "FROM  Alert a INNER JOIN  AlertToEmployee ate   ON a.id = ate.id WHERE a.isDeleted= false" +
        "  AND ate.registrationNumber = ?1 AND ate.isDeleted = false ")
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the INNER JOIN. That's how your query should look like:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.demo.shared.vo.AlertsVO(ate.alert.id, ate.alert.object) " +
       "FROM  AlertToEmployee ate " +
       "WHERE ate.registrationNumber = ?1 AND ate.alert.isDeleted = false")
```

Read more about queries in the Documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql